# How to display the observable data using the service in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***home.component.ts***

```
<h1>{{ (reportsToday$ | async)}}</h1>
<div echarts [options]="alertsDaily$ | async">
<div echarts [options]="alertsToday$ | async">
<div [onDisplay]="alertsDaily$ | async">
```

***report.component.ts***

```
constructor(private report: ReportService) {}

getReports() {
  this.report.getStatusReport();
}
```

***report.service.ts***

```
  displayAlert$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
  reportsToday$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
  alertsToday$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
  alertsDaily$ = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);

constructor() {}

getStatusReport() {

  loading = {
    today: false,
    daily: false
  };

    this.loading.today = true;
    this.loading.daily = true;

    const severities = ['LOW', 'MEDIUM', 'HIGH', 'URGENT'];
    const reportModules = [
      { url: '', params: { to: format(TODAY, DATE_FORMAT).toString(), from: format(TODAY, DATE_FORMAT).toString() } },
      {
        url: 'application1',
        params: { to: format(TODAY, DATE_FORMAT).toString(), from: format(TODAY, DATE_FORMAT).toString() }
      },
      {
        url: 'application2',
        params: {
          to: format(endOfWeek(TODAY), DATE_FORMAT).toString(),
          from: format(startOfWeek(TODAY), DATE_FORMAT).toString()
        }
      },
      {
        url: 'application3',
        params: {
          to: format(endOfWeek(TODAY), DATE_FORMAT).toString(),
          from: format(startOfWeek(TODAY), DATE_FORMAT).toString()
        }
      }
    ];

    const promises = applicationModule.map(
      target =>
        new Promise(resolve => {
          this.notificationService
            .getSummary(target.url, target.params)
            .pipe(take(1))
            .subscribe(
              (result: Response) => 
                resolve({ target, result });
              },
              (err: Error) => {
                // return reject(err);
              }
            );
        })
    );

    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
      const options = this.preConfig;
      const week = this.getWeek();

      results.forEach((res: any) => {
             ....

        if (res.target.url !== '') {
          if (res.target.url === 'application1') {
            ....
            this.loading.today = false;
            this.alertsToday$.next(options.today);
          }else {

            if (res.target.url === 'application2') {
              ...
              ...
              this.loading.daily = false;
              this.alertsDaily$.next(options.daily);
            } else {
              ....
              ....
              this.loading.daily = false;
              this.alertsDaily$.next(options.daily);
            }

          }
       }else {
          this.reportsToday$.next(res.result[0]);
}
    }
   });

}
```

The problem here is it doesn't display the observable data. When I run the application there's no error, but it doesn't display the data of `displayAlert$, reportsToday$, alertsToday$ and alertsDaily$`.

I used service it because, I will use it from the other components.

How to get the observable from service and display it on home component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In component you can't see the variable directly from service. It should be from component itself.

Also you need to subscribe the values you are firing with `.next()`. Unless you subscribe them , the value won't be set.

Answer (score 1):

I think `new BehaviorSubject(undefined);` is causing the problem.
Can you initialize like `new BehaviorSubject([]);` or if it is string then `new BehaviorSubject('');` and if number then `new BehaviorSubject(0);`

I am assuming that you have correctly called service from components.